# os.environ.get returns variable as 'None', even though it can be echoed in terminal. (Python) (Mac OS Catalina)

Tags: python, bash, macos, environment-variables, miniconda

I am trying to call a variable which has been exported in the .bash_profile file. This is how it has been written.

```
export TEST='test'
```

After saving this change in the .bash_profile file, I type this into terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Upon typing `env` into terminal, `TEST=test` is shown. Furthermore, upon typing `echo $TEST`, terminal returns `test`.

The problem I have is that when I try to call this variable into a python script using Pycharm, the script returns `None`.

The code is:

```
import os

print(os.environ.get('TEST'))
```

How can I get the script to output `test`?

It is also worth noting that this is all being done in a Conda virtual environment.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Does your ``.bash_profile`` say ``export TEST='test'`` or just ``TEST='test'``?

Comment: How are you starting Pycharm? It likely isn't started from your shell environment or a descendant of it.

Comment: An environment belongs to a process and is inherited by child processes. It is not a property of your login session or something like that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It says export TEST='test'

Comment: @chepner this could be the issue, how would I rectify this?

Comment: I assume you are double-clicking on a Pycharm icon to start the application, and I also assume there is a way to start Pycharm from the command line (which *might* cause the Pycharm process to be a child/descendent of your login shell).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just figured it out:

In Catalina, Mac now uses `zsh` instead of bash shell, so variables are stored in a `.zshenv` file in your home directory instead of `.bash_profile`:

1. Go to your home directory:

   `cd $HOME`
2. Access your enviroment variable file:

   `nano .zshenv`
3. Create variables

   `TEST='test'` (If you are only going to use it directly from Terminal)

   `export TEST2='test2'` (If you want to access it with `os.environ.get`)

   Save and quit terminal. Open another terminal window and check you can access the variable using:

```
echo $TEST
echo $TEST2
```

4. Access the variable with python

```py
import os
username = os.environ.get('TEST2')
print(username)
```